# Power Pivot files loading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerpivot

I have a sharepoint dev installed on my local win7 box (sql server 2012 is also local and everything is running under my AD account, whihc is an admin account)

I manage to install a PowerPivot Gallery and upload a small excel file with power pivot (3Mb) but when I click on it I just get the "Loading..." screen, no errors, it just stays there for several minutes.

Where can I find out the issue? I mean, I dont even know where to start looking?
I'm very new on sharepoint.

Thanks

Comment: let's take a step back. create an excel file without any powerpivot functionality. load it to the Site Assets library of your site. click on that file/link to open. does the file open? We're attempting to confirm that you're able to open excel files in the browser and that your farm/site has excel services enabled and configured correctly. let me know.

Comment: Hi 1c1cle. Your are rigth, I cant. I just get the same loading message. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: To render excel files in a browser, excel services need to be turned on. check to see if excel services is turned on. You do this in the CA site. It may take some investigation and digging. good luck. let me know...

Comment: hi, that was it. thanks very much. If you want to add an answer with it, I can accept it.

Comment: glad it worked out. have fun. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render excel files in a browser, excel services need to be turned on. check to see if excel services is turned on. You do this in the CA site. It may take some investigation and digging. good luck. let me know...